# load more if condition not working jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a jquery function and I tried to run a condition of if the data is false then load more button will not show but when I tried the if condition is not working please can you let me know where and what mistake I am doing ?

```
function loadmore() {
        var count_data = $('#count_data').val();

        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $('#wait').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('#wait').css('display', 'none');
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'includes/get_data.php',
            data : {count_data : count_data, method: 'count'},
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function(data) {
                if(data == 'No Post Found') {
                    $('#loadmore').css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $('#container_masonry').append(data);
                    var total_count = parseInt(count_data) + parseInt(6);
                    document.getElementById('count_data').value = total_count;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my php code

```
$count = $_POST['count_data'];
        $limit = 6;
        $sql   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $count, $limit"); 
        $i     = 1;

        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 1) {
             echo "Data found";
} else {
            echo "No Post Found";
        }
```

I would appreciate you suggestions and answers that could help me out

Comment: `console.log(data)` in the `success` callback to see what your ajax is receiving - you may be surprised

Comment: outside if condition right before the start of if

Comment: doesn't matter - it wont change within that function - I just want you to see what response you are getting

Comment: @JaromandaX No Post Found

Comment: Can you please try with exit so it will not output anything else after your actual output.
EX:  echo "Data found";exit; and echo "No Post Found";exit;

Comment: OK, well, you're getting what you expected (I expected something different I must admit) - can you verify that both the if and else branches get executed appropriately - and that you don't have any errors in the console

Comment: @JaromandaX I hate when small things make lots of trouble and we stuck up :P please post your 2nd last comment as an answer so I can accept it it worked by using exit :)

Comment: not my post, that was @Kashyap

Comment: ohh sorry @Kashyap kindly post your comment as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with exit so it will not output anything else after your actual output. EX: echo "Data found";exit; and echo "No Post Found";exit;

Comment: Thank you for helping me out